# AWS SNS Message filtering on 'OR' condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, filter, amazon-sns

On the [SNS Message filtering page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering.html) there is an example for AND/OR Logic as follows

**AND logic** : Apply AND logic by using multiple attribute names (keys). For example, the policy:

```
{
    "customer_interests": ["rugby"],
    "price_usd": [{"numeric":[">", 100]}]
}
```

**OR logic** : Apply OR logic by assigning multiple values to an attribute name. For example, the policy attribute:

```
"customer_interests": ["rugby", "football", "baseball"]
```

However how can we apply 'OR' logic for multiple attribute names (keys)

So for example what will be the policy if I want to change the first example

From

(customer_interests="rugby" AND price_usd > 100)

To

(customer_interests="rugby" OR price_usd > 100)

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: No it doesn't support the OR condition across multiple attribute names as of now

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Nov 2023, you can now use the “OR” operator in SNS filter policies. More information: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/11/amazon-sns-message-additional-filtering-operators/

Answer (score 4):

You would have to create 2 separate subscriptions to same endpoint and attach different filters:

For 1st subscription:

```
{
    "customer_interests": ["rugby"]
}
```

For 2nd subscription:

```
{   
   "price_usd": [{"numeric":[">", 100]}]
}
```

I didn't find any way of having OR in single filter, but with creating multiple subscriptions to same endpoint definitely works (used it mysqlf on my account)

Comment: It's not allowing to create multiple subscription to same endpoint from a topic...

Comment: The note on [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/and-or-logic.html) contradicts this. "Currently, you can't use SNS filters to apply OR logic across different message attributes. Instead, you can use multiple SNS subscriptions with **different endpoints** to achieve the same effect."

Comment: @BobHinchliffe that's what my answer states, that it can be done by using 2 subscriptions, so not sure what you mean by it being contradicted by documentation?

Comment: You open with the sentence: "You would have to create 2 separate subscriptions to same endpoint and attach different filters". This is what cannot be done, it needs to be clear that you need two endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I using lambda so I can create new alias for each lambda subscrible. Each lambda will be update with LASTEST.
Subscrible 1.

```
{
    "key1": ["01"],
    "key2": ["123"],
}
```

subscrible: Lambda ABC_1

Subscrible 2.

```
{
    "key1": ["02"],
    "key2": ["456"],
}
```

subscrible: Lambda ABC_1:testing

Answer (score 0):

I may be late for the party. One alternate solution I see is to create two sqs between sns and whatever is subscribing to sns. Then, you attach the filter to sqs. And the lambda will read from sqs. This way you don't to have two end points on lambda. But this one is a bit costly.